# theano vector matrix product along third dimension

Tags: theano

I've got `w = T.matrix('w')` and `X = T.tensor3('X')`.

Assume w is 1xd and X is 3 x 10 x d.

I want as a result a matrix of size 3 x 10 where the i-th row is `w.dot(X[i,:,:].T)`.

Is there a way to do this in theano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for amounts to this in numpy (where I extend the degenerate dimension (1, d) to (6, 5) in order to be general for matrices. If `w` is a vector, then the function may write slightly more simply with 1D arrays)

```
import numpy as np

w = np.arange(6 * 5).reshape(6, 5)
X = np.arange(3 * 10 * 5).reshape(3, 10, 5)

output = np.einsum('ij, klj', w, X)
```

Let's check the zeroth output

```
print w.dot(X[0].T)
print output[:, 0]   # same output as above
```

We can do the same by reshaping the matrices, which will lead us to a valid Theano expression immediately

```
output2 = w.dot(X.reshape(-1, 5).T).reshape((w.shape[0],) + X.shape[:2])
assert (output2 == output).all()
```

Now the Theano expression

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

ww = T.fmatrix()
XX = T.tensor3()

output_expr = ww.dot(XX.reshape((-1, XX.shape[-1])).T).reshape((ww.shape[0], XX.shape[0], XX.shape[1]), ndim=3)

f = theano.function([ww, XX], output_expr)

print f(w.astype('float32'), X.astype('float32'))[:, 0]
```